# How to find the Undefined Behavior that replaces the passed function arguments?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, calling-convention

I am trying to call `fileUtilCopyRecurse` giving it the arguments you can see below. When I step into the function, the arguments 2-4 are replaced with nonsense (argument 1 is ok).

(continued below...)

```
Breakpoint 1, createTestDir (T=0x5555555cabc0 <StaticMem>, MakeTargetNewer=0 '\000') at ../backuper/backuperTest.c:64
64      fileUtilCopyRecurse(T, DirInBoth1, DirInBoth2, false);
(gdb) p DirInBoth1
$1 = (utf8 *) 0x5555555aac68 "../backuper/testdir/1/dir-in-both/"
(gdb) p DirInBoth2
$2 = (utf8 *) 0x5555555aac90 "../backuper/testdir/2/dir-in-both/"
(gdb) s
fileUtilCopyRecurse (T=0x5555555cabc0 <StaticMem>, P=0x5555556bef88 <nonstd_creat_f> "\360\n\354\367\377\177", To=0x5555555a929e "creat", Recurse=1 '\001') at ../fileUtil/fileUtil.c:271
271 fct void fileUtilCopyRecurse(void* T, pathC* P, pathC* To, bool Recurse) { // if dir and Recurse set then recursively copies it
(gdb) p P
$3 = (pathC *) 0x5555556bef88 <nonstd_creat_f> "\360\n\354\367\377\177"
```

At first I thought that the caller .o-File and callee .o-File don't agree on the signature. The typedefs are different because these are two different parts of the codebase, the caller uses utf8 which is typedef char, the callee uses pathC which is typedef const char. So we are giving a char* to a const char* which is fine.

To ensure consistency I checked that the .c files include the same .h file (that specifies `fileUtilCopyRecurse`) and clean-recompiled everything. Then I made sure that `fileUtilCopyRecurse` is not a macro for some reason.

This happens with GCC 9.3.0 on a 64-bit Linux. I have lots of warnings enabled and optimization is disabled (-O0). I brought the code to a different computer with GCC 7.5.0 (also 64-bit Linux), and it works correctly.

So I guess that I have Undefined Behavior somewhere and I ask you for a tip what to look for.

For those who are interested in the disassembly:

```
(gdb) x/6i $pc
=> 0x5555555a7ca8 <createTestDir+245>:  mov    -0x28(%rbp),%rdx
   0x5555555a7cac <createTestDir+249>:  mov    -0x30(%rbp),%rsi
   0x5555555a7cb0 <createTestDir+253>:  mov    -0x38(%rbp),%rax
   0x5555555a7cb4 <createTestDir+257>:  mov    $0x0,%ecx
   0x5555555a7cb9 <createTestDir+262>:  mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x5555555a7cbc <createTestDir+265>:  callq  0x55555559a9de <fileUtilCopyRecurse>
(gdb) si
0x00005555555a7cac  64      fileUtilCopyRecurse(T, DirInBoth1, DirInBoth2, false);
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x5555555a7cac <createTestDir+249>:  mov    -0x30(%rbp),%rsi
(gdb) 
0x00005555555a7cb0  64      fileUtilCopyRecurse(T, DirInBoth1, DirInBoth2, false);
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x5555555a7cb0 <createTestDir+253>:  mov    -0x38(%rbp),%rax
(gdb) 
0x00005555555a7cb4  64      fileUtilCopyRecurse(T, DirInBoth1, DirInBoth2, false);
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x5555555a7cb4 <createTestDir+257>:  mov    $0x0,%ecx
(gdb) 
0x00005555555a7cb9  64      fileUtilCopyRecurse(T, DirInBoth1, DirInBoth2, false);
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x5555555a7cb9 <createTestDir+262>:  mov    %rax,%rdi
(gdb) 
0x00005555555a7cbc  64      fileUtilCopyRecurse(T, DirInBoth1, DirInBoth2, false);
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x5555555a7cbc <createTestDir+265>:  callq  0x55555559a9de <fileUtilCopyRecurse>
(gdb) info reg
rax            0x5555555cabc0      93824992717760
rbx            0x5555555a8670      93824992577136
rcx            0x0                 0
rdx            0x5555555aac90      93824992586896
rsi            0x5555555aac68      93824992586856
rdi            0x5555555cabc0      93824992717760
rbp            0x7fffffffdc90      0x7fffffffdc90
rsp            0x7fffffffdc50      0x7fffffffdc50
r8             0x0                 0
r9             0x7fffffffd830      140737488345136
r10            0x7ffff7db407c      140737351729276
r11            0x246               582
r12            0x5555555610d0      93824992284880
r13            0x7fffffffdf80      140737488347008
r14            0x0                 0
r15            0x0                 0
rip            0x5555555a7cbc      0x5555555a7cbc <createTestDir+265>
eflags         0x207               [ CF PF IF ]
cs             0x33                51
ss             0x2b                43
ds             0x0                 0
es             0x0                 0
fs             0x0                 0
gs             0x0                 0
(gdb)
```

Comment: Run your code through valgrind.  If you're mismanaging memory it will tell you where.

Comment: @dbush I don't think it is about writing into wrong memory addresses: GDB tells me the arguments, I am only stepping into the function and the arguments are changed.

Comment: It could still be that.  Also, if you get warnings when you compile you should fix those first.

Comment: Only if some rogue thread did that, I don't think that is the case here. No, there are no warnings.

Comment: `valgrind --tool=memcheck`   only shows   `still reachable: 2,300 bytes in 5 blocks`

Comment: Are there any messages about an invalid read or invalid write?

Comment: It *only* shows the "still reachable"

Comment: At this point you'll have to add a [mcve] to your question to be able to get any more help.

Comment: Too much work. If there are no good tips then I will switch back to GCC 7.5 or Clang.

Comment: Are you looking at the values before the function prologue has finished? It could be showing you the (uninitialized) values in the shadow space for the parameters before the parameter values have been stored there.

Comment: Does the caller of `fileUtilCopyRecurse` use a correct function prototype? Do the function arguments match the function defintion?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm You are correct! If you copy into an answer then I will accept it. I re-checked it. Usually when stepping lines (instead of assembly-instructions) GDB shows the actual arguments, but in this case (and this GDB-version) not. When I step another line, the arguments are filled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If execution has stopped in the function prologue, the values shown in the debugger for the parameters can be the uninitialized values of the shadow space (stack space where the parameters that are passed in registers are stored on the stack). Continuing execution for another statement should allow the prologue would allow these shadow variables to be populated and let the debugger show the correct values for the parameters.

One way to check if this is the case is to look at a disassembly view to see where, exactly, execution has stopped.

Comment: Confirmed (details see comments)